# Selections do not tally with the number of records moved -- Access 2010

Tags: sql, vba, ms-access, checkbox

I have two tables in MS Access 2010.

### tblStore:

```
ID ItemID ItemName Out (it's a Yes/No field)
1    A1    ALPHA1  
2    A2    ALPHA2  
3    A3    ALPHA3  
4    A4    ALPHA4  
5    B1    BETA1   
6    B2    BETA2   
7    G1    GIGA1   
8    G2    GIGA2
```

### tblOut:

```
ID ItemID ItemName
```

---

I created a form from **tblStore** in tabular layout and added a command button with vba codes:

```
`Private Sub cmdSendOut_Click()
    DoCmd.RunSQL "INSERT INTO tblOut (ItemID, ItemName)" & _
        "SELECT ItemID, ItemName FROM tblStore WHERE (Out = True);"
    
    DoCmd.RunSQL "DELETE FROM tblStore WHERE (Out = True);"
End Sub`
```

**My problem** is: after select 2 records in the form and click the [Send Out] button as shown below, system only show 1 record that need to be appended.
[image]

Can anybody tell me what went wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Please do not edit your title or question to indicate that your issue is 'solved'. This is not a support forum, but a question/answer site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice on the screen shot that one record shows a pencil icon.  That record is not resolved, not saved.  You may find you can save that record before running the queries using VBA:

```
IF Me.Dirty=True Then Me.Dirty =False
```

Then I think you will find both records are captured.  Screen shot very helpful in this case!